# Spark Launcher connection time

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit, spark-launcher

While connecting through spark launcher through remote from one Virtual machine to another Virtual machine in the same host(deploy mode is the client) it is taking 40seconds for connection establishment can anybody suggest me to decrease this time so that I can execute and make use of it in a real-world application. (My main concern is to execute spark submit command programmatically if any other options are there please do suggest me).